# How android call recorders apps works?

Tags: android

There are plenty apps in google play, which can record calls. Some of them just turn on loudspeaker and record sound via microphone, others should be able to record audio steams directly. I know that android provides class for recording. (which doesn't work on lot of devices probably because of some SW restrictions).
So here is my question: Is there possibility to find some device, where call recording will be possible via MediaRecorder(VOICE_CALL)? I found that call recording apps are available for Galaxy SII and SIII so does it means that MediaRecorder(VOICE_CALL) work on these devices?
EDIT------------
Generally, if i want to use MediaRecorder to record calls i need kernel which supports it (for example som custom kernel)?

Comment: Haven't tried the Galaxy SII/III, but voice call recording with VOICE_CALL/VOICE_UPLINK/VOICE_DOWNLINK worked on XPeria P/U/Go/Sola last time I tried it.

Comment: It worked "out of box" or some custom firmware/root was required?

Comment: I've never tried it on a retail phone, but it should work out of the box. I implemented parts of the voice call recording support for those phones at Sony, so unless it got broken afterwards it should work.